# Regarding try/except in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a question. 
Currently I have been developing my own python web app using Django.
I was wondering, is it bad "coding" practice to use try/except throughout the code (even for production level code)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not a bad practice to use try/except for production level code.